# Orchard CMS: Access arbitrary content inside template

Tags: razor, orchardcms

Scenario: HTML snippets created in admin. These are accessed (by name) in a template dynamically, based on state of the template's model's fields.

I have a custom content type and content created. How can I access this content by name from cshtml when it is not part of the model?

Here is psuedo-code of what I want to do.

```
@{
    string title = Model.Title;
    string html = "";

    if(title.Contains("widget-a")) {
        html = GET_CONENT [widget-a].Body;
    }
    else if(title.Contains("widget-b")) {
        html = GET_CONENT [widget-b].Body;
    }
    body =  Model.Html + html;
}

@body
```

I don't want to attach new fields to the content item whose HTML I'm altering.

Comment: You should not be doing database access from a view. The proper place for this is in a part driver for that widget.

Comment: Makes sense. I am migrating a large Wordpress site into Orchard. The original site uses a snippet plugin that replaces text (e.g., "[widget-a] with HTML defined in the admin. Trying to replicate. I'll keep at it.

Comment: If you can give more details about what exactly you're trying to do, it would be easier to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'd be happy too. I'm importing content from Wordpress. Inside each post content contains a tag such as [widget-*]. Wordpress has a plugin called Code Snippets that allows me to define html in the admin for each [widget-*] tag. When the page is output, the tags are replaced with the snippet html. I want to continue using the tags in Orchard. I need to be able to change the tag html and have it be reflected across all posts. I'd like to define my snippets in a custom content part, which I can edit in Orchard admin.

Comment: I need a way to search/replace the tag for the snippet when composing the body part. Few more things: each post can have one or more tags, tags can be placed anywhere in the body. My initial idea was the do the replacing in my Parts.Common.Body-BlogPost.cshtml alternate, as I modify the html. You suggested using the driver. I don't understand how this would work. Don't I need to attach the custom part to the model in question (BlogPost) to  access to it in the driver? How would this work when there can by n tags per post?

Comment: Now that I understand your scenario better, I think you can use the tokens filter that comes standard with the latest Orchard 1.x. This will do replacements of token strings such as `#{Content.Fields.WidgetA.Text}`. You can then add a WidgetA text field to your content type, and if I understood your scenario correctly, that should be all you need.

Comment: Actually I may have misunderstood you. Is the content for WidgetA defined globally on the site, or is it a field of the current item? If it's globally on the site, you may have to add it as a setting by altering the Site content type. It should still be accessible through tokens under `#{Site}`.

Comment: Great! The html snippet is defined globally. The only reference I have to the snippet is via the tags in the post html of Body part. Is this available in 1.8.1?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have a 1.8.1 handy right now. Maybe try it if you have one?

Comment: Looks like this work fine in 1.8.x. Using the approach from http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Adding-custom-settings. How do I use the #{Site} token you mentioned?

Comment: Aha. Found this: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/260728
All good now. Thanks for the help.